# Magento install failed on cPanel

Tags: magento2, database, hosting, cpanel, mysql8

When i try to install Magento v2.4.3 through installatron on cpanel, it throws an error :

Error: A database query has failed. Is the entered database information correct? Does the account have available disk space?

arguments = array (  0 => 'SELECT `user_id` FROM `mg_admin_user` WHERE `is_active`='1' ORDER BY `user_id` ASC LIMIT 1',  1 => NULL,  2 => 'user_id',)

Any Help!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you please first of the delete all database table if added.
2. Now you can copy source file in your root directory
3. Now open terminal and run below command for magento installation.

   php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/" --db-user="" --db-password="" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="" --admin-firstname="Mage" --admin-lastname="developer" --admin-email="test@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --backend-frontname="admin" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1"

Make sure you can create database properly and added all access.

if any error showing then message me with screenshot so i will help you.